# How to combine multiple HTTP calls in Angular using RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make multiple HTTP calls simultaneously in my Angular service and I want to combine the responses into a single object. How can I do this using RxJS?

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getData1(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('https://api.example.com/data1');
   }

   getData2(): Observable<any> {
     return this.http.get('https://api.example.com/data2');
   }
}
```

Comment: You may find some further inspiration in [this article](https://medium.com/p/ef636c9af19a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using forkjoin

```
getCombinedData(): Observable<any> {
     return forkJoin([this.getData1(), this.getData2()]);
   }
```

```
combineData() {
    this.dataService.getCombinedData().subscribe((responses) => {
      const [data1, data2] = responses;
    });
```

By using concatMap: Use concatMap to make sequential HTTP calls and combine their results. This is useful when you want to ensure that the calls are made one after another.